# Probability Uniform Distribution Set Up Integral

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

Consider a $1$ meter stick and suppose you break it into two pieces $X$ meters from the end, where $X \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$. What is the expected length of the longer piece (after it is broken)?

So the integral would be from $x$ to $1$, but what would be the integrand?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the longer piece is $\max\{X,1-X\}$. So your expectation would be $\int_0^1 \max\{x,1-x\}\,dx$.

Comment: Is this integral possible to solve?

Comment: or is the better to leave it in this form?

Comment: Yes, you can solve the integral by breaking it into two pieces - one for the subinterval where $x>1-x$, and one for the subinterval where $x\le 1-x$.

Comment: So would it be integral from 0 to x max(x, 1-x), and then another integral from x to 1 max(x, 1-x)?

Comment: You can't integrate to or from $x$: $x$ is your variable of integration.

Comment: Oh sorry, so its both integrals from 0 to 1? but then when we integrate it becomes x^2/2 from 0 to 1, and x-x^2/2 from 0 to 1, which in end is just 1?

Comment: No - to evaluate $\int_0^1 \max\{x,1-x\}\,dx$ you should integrate $x$ from $0$ to $1/2$ and $1-x$ from $1/2$ to $1$, since $\max\{x,1-x\}=x$ when $x\le 1/2$ and $1-x$ when $x\ge 1/2$.

Comment: But once I integrate it, it becomes 0 now? Sorry I am still very confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26417/discussion-between-alexander-dunlap-and-dee-chantelle).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by integration.

$\begin{align}
E[\max\{X, 1-X\}] 
& = \int_0^{1}\max\{x, 1-x\}\operatorname d x 
\\ & = \int_0^{1/2} 1-x\operatorname d x + \int_{1/2}^1 x\operatorname d x
\\ & = \big[x-x^2/2\big]_{x=0}^{x=1/2} + \big[x^2/2\big]_{x=1/2}^{x=1}
\\ & = 3/4
\end{align}$

**Alternatively:**  The break occurs uniformly, half the time it will be nearer one end and half the time it will be nearer the other, so we can say that the break results in the longer piece's length having a uniform distribution between $(1/2..1)$, and thus the mean longer-piece-length is $3/4$ (as expected).

Comment: would it be 1/4?

Comment: @Dee Close, but you have the wrong end of the stick.  Would you expect the **larger** piece be less than 1/2?

Comment: no, so it would be 3/4?

Comment: $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ @DeeChantelle